# How can I replace a word with another word in a whole hierarchy of files

Tags: bash, shell-script, replace

I have a hierarchy of files and two words: word1 and word2.
In this hierarchy of files, some of them can contain word1. I want to replace every occurrence of word1 with word2. It is possible using a single bash command or I have to develop a script for this task?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `single bash command` - there isn't even a dozen bash commands that could do that, you'll need to use some commands that are not in bash for sure ... like maybe `grep` and `sed` for instance

Comment: by the way, your statement is confusing ... *some files contain word1*, and you want to *change word2 to word1* ... so, you want to only change word2 to word1 if the file already contains word1?

Comment: a simplistic way ... `for f in $(grep -rl word1 dir); do sed -i 's/word2/word1/g' $f; done` - of course ... this would change word2xyz to word1xyz ... which may not be what you want

Comment: can be done with only sed. please provide example code and what you have tried so far

Comment: @Bravo, Thank you, your commands work properly for my task

Comment: @alecxs - `can be done with only sed` - are you sure? I've never tried using `sed` on more than one file at a time

Comment: drop the loop and replace f with dir/*

Comment: What do you mean with "Hieararchy of files"? Does it mean you have nested subdirectories that you need to recursively traverse?

Comment: @AdminBee, yes, this is what I intended. I solved this, thanks to Bravo

Comment: @Fredi, if you "solved this", you really ought to show how, as an answer, so that everyone can benefit from what you learnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, thanks to @Bravo.

This is the bash script:

```
for f in $(grep -rl word1 dir); do sed -i 's/word1/word2/g' $f; done
```

Basically, this script iterates over each file recursively in a directory (dir) that contains word1. After that, it applies the sed command that replaces each occurrences of word1 with word2.